# PHP/jquery autocomplete not loading JSON_ERROR_UTF8

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've got the following code which works only for 70 items. the moment I added the 71st item to the DB it fails to work.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

      //autoComplete() returns a php array with all the products
    <?php $productArray = autoComplete();?>

    var js_products_array = <?php echo json_encode($productArray); ?>;

    var result;

     for(var i=0;i<js_products_array.length;i++){
        result += js_products_array[i]  + ', ';
    }
     //printing js_products_array 

    document.write(result);


    $( "#autocompleteID" ).autocomplete({
                    source: js_products_array
                 });

...
```

I can see that `js_products_array`  holds all the values but the autocomplete feature fails to work. The moment i remove the 71st item from the DB it works again.

I'm puzzled as to what's causing this. Would appreciate some help, cheers.

Comment: what is your 71 st item ????

Comment: hi, its just a string. I have tried multiple different strings but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code fixed the problem: `mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");`

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, try to use

```
json_last_error


var last_error = <?php echo json_last_error(); ?>;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

to check the problem

or

limit the number of records , `it is easy to limit the number of records in database level`

**UPDATE**

try

in your server function `autoComplete()` before returning the result to the view use this function to utf-8 encode the array

```
utf8_encode_deep($result_from_db);

function utf8_encode_deep(&$input) {
    if (is_string($input)) {
        $input = utf8_encode($input);
    } else if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach ($input as &$value) {
            utf8_encode_deep($value);
        }

        unset($value);
    } else if (is_object($input)) {
        $vars = array_keys(get_object_vars($input));

        foreach ($vars as $var) {
            utf8_encode_deep($input->$var);
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use

`json_encode($productArray);`

Comment: 'or limit the number of record' I don't see how that will work since i need all the products to be loaded so it will be available in the javascript array `js_products_array ` for the autocomplete feature.

Comment: as per your recommendation i ran `json_last_error`. on the 71st record it returned: 5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8..trying to figure out what this means..ok so it means Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded. Any suggestions on what i need to do to fix this? thanks!

Comment: check my new update . and also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php